# Passing a null DateTime to php function

Tags: php, datetime

I have a function in php that I want to accept either a DateTime object or null. E.g.

```
function foo(DateTime $aDate){
   if ($aDate == null){
       echo "You passed a null variable";
   } else {
       echo "You passed the date " . $aDate->format('Y-m-d');
   }
}
```

Trouble is, because the function expects a DateTime object it flips out when I pass null to it and gives an error:

```
Catchable fatal error: Argument 1 passed to foo() must be an instance of DateTime, null given,...
```

How can I pass null to the function and avoid this error?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Change from this:

```
function foo(DateTime $aDate){
```

To this:

```
function foo($aDate){
```

---

But if you still want to make sure the object passed is a `DateTime` object you can do this:

```
function foo(DateTime $aDate = null){
```

---

See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8523033/561731) for more examples of Type Hinting.

Comment: Interesting that it doesn't allow `null` with type hinting. Part of me feels it should.

Comment: OK so what is the point in putting `DateTime` in the paramater list of the function if you can still pass a DateTime without it?

Comment: @JasonMcCreary Ahh found the solution!

Comment: Yeah, the update makes more sense. I would like to force passing either a `DateTime` or `null`.

Comment: This is possible in PHP 7.1 and above, see @pcmoreno's answer. IMO, his answer should be the accepted one now.

Answer (score 7):

add a `?` to the type hint.

```
    function foo(?DateTime $aDate){
        if ($aDate == null){
            echo "You passed a null variable";
        } else {
            echo "You passed the date " . $aDate->format('Y-m-d');
        }
    }
```

This way only an explicit NULL or DateTime are allowed.

Comment: Note that this is only possible in PHP >= 7.1.

Comment: I was _just_ too late to edit: The file where the function is _called from_ must have `declare(strict_types = 1);` as its first statement, or it won't be enforced.

Answer (score 3):

Make $aDate optional.

```
function foo(DateTime $aDate = null) {
    if($aDate) {
        //parse date
    } else {
        //null given
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The way to do it is to assign a default value in the function declaration:-

```
function foo(DateTime $aDate = null){
   if (!$aDate){
       echo "You passed a null variable";
   } else {
       echo "You passed the date " . $aDate->format('Y-m-d');
   }
}
```