# Laravel 4 Inversion of Control

Tags: laravel, laravel-4

I'm watching a video explaining the basics of laravel's IoC container, and I'm having trouble understanding what this code is doing. Specifically, I don't understand the parameter in the constructor function of the UserRepository class. I haven't had much luck finding an example of this syntax on the php site.

http://vimeo.com/53009943

```
<?php

 class UserRepository {

    protected $something;

    public function __construct(Something $something)

    {

        $this->something = $something;

    }
}

class Something {}

?>
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Quoting [Laravel's documentation](http://laravel.com/docs/ioc):

> There are two ways the IoC container can resolve dependencies: via
>   Closure callbacks or automatic resolution.

But first, what is a dependency? In the code that you have posted, the `UserRepository` class has one dependency, which is the `Something` class. It means that `UserRepository` is going to depend on `Something` somewhere in its code. Instead of using it directly, by doing something like this

```
$something = new Something;
$something->doSomethingElse();
```

it is **being injected** in its constructor function. This technique is known as **[dependency injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dependency_injection)**. So, these code snippets would do the same, without and with dependency injection.

```
// Without DI
class UserRepository {

    public function doSomething()
    {
        $something = new Something();
        return $something->doSomethingElse();
    }


}
```

Now, using DI, which would be the same as you posted:

```
// With DI
class UserRepository {

    public function __construct(Something $something)
    {
        $this->something = $something;
    }

    public function doSomething()
    {
        return $this->something->doSomethingElse();
    }

}
```

You are saying that you don't understand the parameter being passed in the constructor `__constructor(Something $something)`. That line is telling PHP that the constructor expects one parameter, `$something`, which **must be an instance of the `Something` class**. This is known as [type hinting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8522984/type-hinting-default-parameters). Passing a parameter which is not an instance of `Something` (or any subclass), will throw an exception.

---

Finally, let's go back to the IoC container. We've said before that its function is to resolve dependencies, and it can do it in two ways.

First one, Closure callbacks:

```
// This is telling Laravel that whenever we do
// App::make('user.repository'), it must return whatever
// we are returning in this function
App::bind('UserRepository', function($app)
{
    return new UserRepository(new Something);
});
```

Second one, automatic resolution

```
 class UserRepository {

    protected $something;


    public function __construct(Something $something)

    {

        $this->something = $something;

    }
}

// Now when we do this
// Laravel will be smart enough to create the constructor
// parameter for you, in this case, a new Something instance
$userRepo = App::make('UserRepository');
```

This is specially helpful and allows your classes to be more flexible, when using interfaces as parameters for your constructors.

Comment: Great explanation! I have been reading up on this for a while trying to understand how it al works. This makes way more sense now... I'm still new to PHP frameworks, laravel is my first one!

Comment: Don't worry if all these concepts sound strange right now. They will become clear as you get more experienced. We've been all there ;)